# mod rewrite mystery, redirect to external website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am setting up some mod rewrite redirects for particular URLs; we are launching a new site and need to send a few URLs to the old web site until migration is complete.  I have copied the format of another site I did this with, with the exception being that the other site was apache 2.4 and this one is 2.2.  Here's my (so far) very minimal .htaccess and the new site, domain.org:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^services/membership/login/login\.html$ http://oldsite.domain.org/services/membership/login/login.html [L]
```

I can verify that mod_rewrite is enabled because I can get a log to generate, but I can't make sense of the log.  The results of browsing to http://domain.org/services/membership/login/login.html, which is a CMS, is that the domain doesn't change and I get the content of the CMS home page but the css and images aren't loaded.  This makes no sense to me.  If I got a match on the rule, the redirect should happen and I should get the right result.  If I don't get a match I should get a 404 because there is no URL for this.

Comment: Or both domains hosted on the same web server? If so, in what constellation?

Comment: No, completely different servers.

Comment: Well then what does the rewrite log show? (Please show output for one single request only, clear it before if necessary.)

Comment: Sorry, this is going to be big because of all the cms calls that shouldn't be made

Comment: Much too large to post here.  I will include just to the line where index.php is referenced, which is the first thing that SHOULDN'T be there:

Comment: Well if you clear the rewrite log and then request the login page directly in your browser, it should be the first request showing up in there … and after that, when other requests start getting processed, you can cut it off …

Comment: 174.75.64.24 - - [14/Feb/2014:15:18:08 --0800] [cms.host.domain.org/sid#b85a2be0][rid#b887ef68/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /services/membership/login/login.html
174.75.64.24 - - [14/Feb/2014:15:18:08 --0800] [cms.host.domain.org/sid#b85a2be0][rid#b887ef68/initial] (1) pass through /services/membership/login/login.html
174.75.64.24 - - [14/Feb/2014:15:18:08 --0800] [cms.host.domain.org/sid#b85a2be0][rid#b887ef68/initial] (2) [perdir /home/domain/public_html/] rewrite 'services/membership/login/login.html' -> 'index.php'

Comment: No, a single request is HUGE because of all the resources processed by the CMS.  Log level 2.

Comment: That log excerpt does not indicate that there was even an _attempt_ made to match the request URI against the pattern … it just says “pass through” immediately, and that is definitively wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you are able to use the following in your .htaccess:

```
Redirect http://domain.org/services/membership/login/login.html http://oldsite.domain.org/services/membership/login/login.html
```

Or

```
Redirect /services/membership/login/login.html http://oldsite.domain.org/services/membership/login/login.html
```

For Reference: http://www.htaccessredirect.co.uk